# How to render a block in a template?

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

I installed the module "Shariff Social Media Buttons" for "Drupal 8" :

```
https://www.drupal.org/project/shariff
```

This module once installed, add a block in :

```
/admin/structure/block
```

I want to display this block in a template :

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/rendering-blocks-with-twig-tweak

I tried with the following code :

```
{{ drupal_entity('block', shariffsharebuttons) }}
```

But the block does not work (it is not rendered on my page)

[image]

[image]

```
drush ev 'print_r(\Drupal::configFactory()->listAll("block.block."));'
```

[image]

Comment: Just a wild guess, but: try using quotes around the block name `{{ drupal_entity('block', 'shariffsharebuttons') }}`

Comment: @Hudri Yes that's right. Thank you. Drupal documentation is not correct

Comment: `shariffsharebuttons` without quotes is a variable (which content is most likely empty, why you didn't get any result), while `'shariffsharebuttons'` is a constant / a string value. The doc is not really wrong, they just didn't explain the Twig syntax.

Comment: Docs seem to be correct. They also suggest `{{ drupal_block('system_breadcrumb_block') }}`. And they explicitly say:  **Note that the plugin_id needs to be wrapped in quotes.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) Module, will gives you twig extension called `drupal_block`and you can render your block like the following :

```
{{ drupal_block('shariff_block') }}
```

Take a look to the module [Cheat sheet](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet-8x-2x) for more info.

**Note :** [Shariff](https://www.drupal.org/project/shariff) Module provide block with the id `shariff_block` not `shariffsharebuttons`.

Comment: Any idea about doing this without installing new module?